# How to add my server side PHP code to this form wizard?

Tags: javascript, php

I have developed a simple 3 step form wizard for registration.

All the client side validation (JavaScript) is working.

The problem is when a user gets to the last stage and click submit, it does nothing.

I want it to direct to the PHP code I have written.

**Update** The next button does nothing when I click on it after updating my html code

**Updated HTML code**

```
<form action="register.php">
    <div id ="personal-form">
        <h4><b>Personal Details:</b></h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
            First Name
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            Last Name
            <label class="sr-only" for="last-name">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="lastname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            Phone Number
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="has-error" id="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="f1-buttons">
            <button type="button" id="first-next" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
        </div>
</div>

    <div id="store-form">
    ........

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous" id="first- 
    previous">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" 
    id="second-next">Next</button></center>                 
    </div>

    <div id="account-form">

    ........

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous" id="second- 
    previous">Previous</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-next" id="submit">Submit</button> 
    </center>
    </div>

   </form>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
function init() {
    //hide the other two forms
    $("#store-form").hide();
    $("#account-form").hide();

    //$("#first-next").addClass("disabled");

    //var state2 = $("#state").val();

    /*$("#state").change(function ()
    {
        var state2 = $("#state").val();
        alert(state2);
    })*/

    //alert(state2);

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    })

    $.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6
        // && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long');//'Your password must be at least 6 characters long, contain at least on e number and a character');

    //The method for all select options
    $.validator.addMethod('checkSelect', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (value != "Please choose...")
        // && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'You must select an option');//'Your password must be at least 6 characters long, contain at least on e number and a character');

    $("#personal-form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                nowhitespace: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                nowhitespace: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: 'Please enter your first name',
                nowhitespace: 'Please enter a valid first name',
                lettersonly: 'Please enter only alphabets'
            },
            lastname: {
                required: 'Please enter your first name',
                nowhitespace: 'Please enter a valid last name',
                lettersonly: 'Please enter only alphabets'
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter a valid phone no"
            }
        }
    });

    /*if($("#personal-form").valid() == true)
    {
        $("#first-next").removeClass("disabled");
        alert($("#personal-form").valid());
    }*/

    if ($("#first-next").click(function () {
        if ($("#personal-form").valid() == true) {
        //$("#first-next").removeClass("disabled");
        //alert($("#personal-form").valid());

            $("#personal-form").hide();
            $("#store-form").fadeIn();
            $("#account-form").hide();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }
    else {
        //$("#error-msg").html("Please correct all errors before clicking next");
    }
    }));

    /*$("#firstname").on('change', function() {
        if($("#firstname").valid() == true)
        {
            console.log("test");
            alert("It worked");
        }
    });*/

    //$('#firstname').on('input', function()
    //{
    //var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    //alert(firstname);
    //alert("hello");
    //console.log("test");
    //alert("You just typed something in the firstname field");
    //});

    $("#store-form").validate({
        rules: {
            storename: {
                required: true
            },
            state: {
                required: true,
                checkSelect: true
            },
            lga: {
                required: true,
                checkSelect: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true,
            },
            category: {
                required: true,
                checkSelect: true
            },
            description: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            storename: {
                required: "Please enter the name of your store"
            },
            address: {
                required: "Please enter the address of your store"
            },
            description: {
                required: "Briefly descibe what you sell or do"
            }
        }
    });

    if ($("#second-next").click(function () {
        if ($("#store-form").valid() == true) {
        //$("#first-next").removeClass("disabled");
        //alert($("#personal-form").valid());

            $("#personal-form").hide();
            $("#store-form").hide();
            $("#account-form").fadeIn();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }
    else {
        //$("#error-msg").html("Please correct all errors before clicking next");
    }
    }));

    if ($("#first-previous").click(function () {
        $("#personal-form").fadeIn();
        $("#store-form").hide();
        $("#account-form").hide();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }));

    $("#account-form").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                strongPassword: true
            },
            password2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email address',
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            password: {
                required: 'Please enter your password',
                strongPassword: "Your password is not strong enough"
            },
            password2: {
                required: 'Please enter your password',
                equalTo: "Both passwords don't match"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#email").on('input', function () {
        if ($("#email").valid() == true) {
            //console.log("test");
            //alert("It worked");

            var email = $("#email").val();

            $("#check-email-server").load('php/check_email.php', { "email": email });
        }
    });

    $("#email").on('focusout', function () {
        if ($("#email").valid() == true) {
            //console.log("test");
            //alert("It worked");

            var email = $("#email").val();

            $("#check-email-server").load('php/check_email.php', { "email": email });
        }
    });

    if ($("#second-previous").click(function () {
        $("#personal-form").hide();
        $("#store-form").fadeIn();
        $("#account-form").hide();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }));
}
```

The three forms should all connect to 1 PHP file.

The problem is when I click submit it does nothing.

How do I connect the three different forms together and make the submit button work?

[image: 1st form]

[image: 2nd form]

[image: 3rd form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last button should be of type "submit" `<button type="submit">` otherwise a normal "button" doesn't submit the form (or maybe you have to write a js click event to submit the form.)

AND

You must put all inputs in the same form to send them to php, consider to replace forms with divs and wrap them inside an unique form. If you use 3 different forms only the input elements of the last form will be sent to backend but I think you need all inputs.

This is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2sdtjydu/1/

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id ="personal-form">
        <h4><b>Personal Details:</b></h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
            First Name
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            Last Name
            <label class="sr-only" for="last-name">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="lastname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            Phone Number
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="has-error" id="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="f1-buttons">
            <button type="button" id="first-next" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
        </div>
</div>

    <div id="store-form">
    ........

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous" id="first- 
    previous">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" 
    id="second-next">Next</button>           
    </div>

    <div id="account-form">

    ........

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous" id="second- 
    previous">Previous</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-next" id="submit">Submit</button> 
    </div>

   </form>
```

And this is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //hide the other two forms
    $("#store-form").hide();
    $("#account-form").hide();

    //$("#first-next").addClass("disabled");

    //var state2 = $("#state").val();

    /*$("#state").change(function ()
    {
        var state2 = $("#state").val();
        alert(state2);
    })*/

    //alert(state2);

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    })

    $.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6
        // && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long');//'Your password must be at least 6 characters long, contain at least on e number and a character');

    //The method for all select options
    $.validator.addMethod('checkSelect', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (value != "Please choose...")
        // && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'You must select an option');//'Your password must be at least 6 characters long, contain at least on e number and a character');
$("form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                nowhitespace: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                nowhitespace: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
            },
                    storename: {
                required: true
            },
            state: {
                required: true,
                checkSelect: true
            },
            lga: {
                required: true,
                checkSelect: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true,
            },
            category: {
                required: true,
                checkSelect: true
            },
            description: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },
                        email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                strongPassword: true
            },
            password2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: 'Please enter your first name',
                nowhitespace: 'Please enter a valid first name',
                lettersonly: 'Please enter only alphabets'
            },
            lastname: {
                required: 'Please enter your first name',
                nowhitespace: 'Please enter a valid last name',
                lettersonly: 'Please enter only alphabets'
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter a valid phone no"
            },
            storename: {
                required: "Please enter the name of your store"
            },
            address: {
                required: "Please enter the address of your store"
            },
            description: {
                required: "Briefly descibe what you sell or do"
            },
            email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email address',
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            password: {
                required: 'Please enter your password',
                strongPassword: "Your password is not strong enough"
            },
            password2: {
                required: 'Please enter your password',
                equalTo: "Both passwords don't match"
            }
        }
    });


    /*if($("#personal-form").valid() == true)
    {
        $("#first-next").removeClass("disabled");
        alert($("#personal-form").valid());
    }*/

    if ($("#first-next").click(function () {
        if ($("#personal-form :input").valid() == true) {
        //$("#first-next").removeClass("disabled");
        //alert($("#personal-form").valid());

            $("#personal-form").hide();
            $("#store-form").fadeIn();
            $("#account-form").hide();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }
    else {
        //$("#error-msg").html("Please correct all errors before clicking next");
    }
    }));

    /*$("#firstname").on('change', function() {
        if($("#firstname").valid() == true)
        {
            console.log("test");
            alert("It worked");
        }
    });*/

    //$('#firstname').on('input', function()
    //{
    //var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    //alert(firstname);
    //alert("hello");
    //console.log("test");
    //alert("You just typed something in the firstname field");
    //});


    if ($("#second-next").click(function () {
        if ($("#store-form :input").valid() == true) {
        //$("#first-next").removeClass("disabled");
        //alert($("#personal-form").valid());

            $("#personal-form").hide();
            $("#store-form").hide();
            $("#account-form").fadeIn();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }
    else {
        //$("#error-msg").html("Please correct all errors before clicking next");
    }
    }));

    if ($("#first-previous").click(function () {
        $("#personal-form").fadeIn();
        $("#store-form").hide();
        $("#account-form").hide();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }));

    $("#email").on('input', function () {
        if ($("#email").valid() == true) {
            //console.log("test");
            //alert("It worked");

            var email = $("#email").val();

            $("#check-email-server").load('php/check_email.php', { "email": email });
        }
    });

    $("#email").on('focusout', function () {
        if ($("#email").valid() == true) {
            //console.log("test");
            //alert("It worked");

            var email = $("#email").val();

            $("#check-email-server").load('php/check_email.php', { "email": email });
        }
    });

    if ($("#second-previous").click(function () {
        $("#personal-form").hide();
        $("#store-form").fadeIn();
        $("#account-form").hide();

        //$("#error-msg").html("");
    }));
});
```

Comment: I did that but the NEXT button now does absolutely nothing. Check my updated html code

Comment: You're using validate on div and you should use it in the form. Somewhere there are if($(..).click()) i cannot understand the if on a click. I edited my reply with your code revised and I create a fiddle to better try it.

Comment: Your Next code is working but I am finding it difficult implementing it with my JS code to make the validation work as well...I am new to JS.

Comment: If you wrote the previous code you should understand how to go on, start from a non-validate form, make it work, and the add validation options.

Comment: I didn't write the JS code...I tried but still cant get it to work with the validation.

Comment: Try my updated fiddle, I merged the validation of 3 form to one